# Residual vs. Predicted Plot- Thick linear trend. How do I interpret this for assumptions?

Tags: multiple-regression, residuals, assumptions

[image]

Trying to interpret these graphs in order to understand if this model meets the assumptions for multiple linear regression.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If the axis labels are to be trusted, this model does not satisfy the assumptions. (Obviously.) What goes wrong and what can be done about it is impossible to tell without further information: What does the model look like that you fit? What kind of data do you have? What do you want to research? etc.

Comment: It would help to tell us what your predictors are like. I assume you have either many categorical ones or a mixture with continuous ones with a smallish number of values. It would also help to know what your outcome is like. Again I assume it is bounded above and below with many values at the extremes. You could tell u all these things rather than let us guess and then someone might be able to give you helpful advice.

Comment: I agree with @mdewey. The standardization here obscures a little what is happening. Consider the definition residual $=$ observed response $-$ fitted response. So in the original units the distinct values of the observed lie on lines with the same intercept and slope $-1$. You have clear diagonal bounds which may be as simple as corresponding to observed $= 0, 1$. In other words, it appears that you have fitted a hyperplane to a bounded response. That raises the question of whether any predicted values are outside those bounds. Better to use a flavour of regression that respects the bounds.

Comment: Dependent variable: Attributed Charisma Independent variable: Narcissism Moderator variable: Value congruence interaction term. control variables: age, sex, party affiliation. does this graph appear to meet linearity assumptions? Just not normality and possible heteroscadicity? Thank you!

Comment: charisma and narcissism and value congruence used a likert scale. Sex and party dummy variables

Comment: If you are concerned about independence of errors as you suggest in a comment then you need to think about the science of what you are doing. A plot is not going to reveal whether the observations are independent or not as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

The lines in the figure arise because your dependent variable has a hard minimum and a hard maximum (although, because everything is standardized, I can't tell what the actual values of the extrema are). You wouldn't usually see these lines in a residual plot of data that was really generated by a linear regression model, because such a model postulates that the error is normally distributed, and a normal distribution has no extrema.

Of course, real data is rarely if ever generated by a neat statistical model, so the answer to the question "Does my data meet the assumptions of such-and-such a model?" is almost always "no".

Comment: Still bit confused at the consensus here?

Comment: Also which plot would test independence of errors?

Comment: Now I think it's a pretty good answer, so not only is my objection gone, I've upvoted accordingly. You should feel free to remove any of your responses to me as you wish.

Comment: There is a pretty strong consensus here. A bounded response (dependent variable in your terminology) which you explain as on a Likert scale could be modelled by some sort of ordered logit or probit, for example. If you insist on linear regression, you should not be surprised by the sharp bounds on the plot, which have been explained as inevitable side-effects of the bounded scale.